# How to receive specific rows in inner join SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, inner-join

How can I do inner join and choose only one row from rows that have the same columns?

for example:

[image] 
[image]

if I execute the query:

```
SELECT t1.col1, t2.col3 
FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 
ON t1.col2=t2.col2;
```

I will get the table

[image]

But, I want to receive only one row (the top one) for each value in col1

[image]

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: "(the top one)" - how are you *defining* top in this circumstance? Tables have no inherent order. So, is it the row with the *lowest* `col3` value? Or some other rule using some other (not shown here) column(s)?

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen and what if the values in col3 was "a,b,c" instead "10,20,30"? is MIN works?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever  top is what display upper in the table

Comment: Tables have **no** inherent order. Which row is displayed "upper in the table" can change *every* time you query the table.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen in a second thought, min will not return the top one..

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever So why if I do "insert into" 3 times, the order that they display will be exactly in the order that I insert them?

Comment: @OrK The reason you see them in the same order as you insert is because "you're lucky". As Damien says - it's not guaranteed as the data is not sorted/ordered. If you want to have a fixed order - introduce a sortkey that have the sorting defined.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen and Damien_The_Unbeliever : OK, I understand.. I will add unique column for order, and then I will select by it.. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It will also make your life a lot easier as you then have values to order by directly without doing all sorts of stuff :)

Comment: I know you've already worked around your issue as we suggested you should. But just to address the question "So why if I do "insert into" 3 times, the order that they display will be exactly in the order that I insert them?" - For the same reason that this query - `SELECT MONTH(GETDATE())` always returns the number 6. Really, you can run it as many times as you like - test it for two weeks if you like. But I'd still not recommend it to someone as a solution to getting the number 6. Because it's programming by coincidence and/or observation, rather than what is *guaranteed* to work.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to try a window function

```
SELECT T.col1, T.col3 
FROM (
   SELECT t1.col1, t2.col3 , 
          ROW_NUMBER () over (partition by t1.col1 order by  t2.col3) as orden
   FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 
       ON t1.col2=t2.col2) as T
WHERE T.orden = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, A great Idea!

Answer (score 2):

One more way with OUTER APPLY:

```
SELECT t1.col1,p.col3
FROM t1
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 * 
    FROM t2 
    WHERE t1.col2 = t2.col2) as p
```

Output:

```
col1    col3
1       10
2       30
```

Comment: Great if you found something new! More technical details and examples you can get from here https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1958/sql-server-cross-apply-and-outer-apply/

Answer (score 1):

```
You can also use below

Select Col1,Col3 From (
    SELECT Col1,Col3,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY t2.Col2 ORDER BY Col3) rank
        FROM   T2 JOIN T1 on T2.col2=T1.col2) Tr where rank=1
```

Comment: @OrK: is not the same since you may have multiple rows with rank=1

Comment: Agree with @vercelli but this will work with your problem.

Answer (score 1):

All answers are right.. but some will bring to different or even worst, unpredictable output (non deterministic).

in solution 1) **group by/min** from @AllanS.Hansen and @GiorgosBetsos you will receive only one row of t2 for each row in t1. 
The row will be choosen using the min() function that is defined for almost every datatype.

solution 2) **row_number=1** from @vercelli is the same of solution 1) it keep the first value order by col3 ASC this is the same of MIN()

pay ATTENTION!
solution 3) **outer apply** from @gofr1 is similar, but it does not guarantee the output, top function can give different results at each run, if you do not specify an **order by col3** clause (the optimizer will decide depending on indexes or clustered keys). If you specify it, it will give same output of solution 1) and solution 2)

you have to decide what TOP means for you, it could be different from the meaning of sql server TOP function.

I think the best solution is to add a column with sort order.

You can use an integer column, like 1,2,3 for sort order, or you can use an identity.
In this case you will also have the "**insertion order**"

I will avoid the **OUTER APPLY** because it executed for each row of t1 and it is slower than other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query like the following:

```
SELECT t1.col1, t2.col3 
FROM t1 
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT col2, MIN(col3) AS col3
   FROM t2 
   GROUP BY col2
) AS t2 ON t1.col2=t2.col2;
```

Comment: Nope. This will give the minimum not first value for col3

Comment: @ChaosLegion There is no such thing as *first value*. SQL tables are *unordered sets* and precedence is governed by a particular column. From the context provided in the OP I assume that the field in this case is `col3`.

Comment: Yes. His requirement is the TOP first. Is it difficult to change in your answer?

Comment: @ChaosLegion - until the OP gives us a *usable* definition of "top", I'd say it's currently impossible to change the answer.

Comment: OK, I understand.. I will add unique column for order, and then I will select by it.. Thanks a lot!